# Operator overloading for sort() function on vector no match for ‘operator<’ error

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I am new to C++ and am trying to have the sort() function sort my array of Event objects. I have overloaded the < operator for Event objects, but when using sort() to compare two Event objects, I am getting a: no match for ‘operator<’ error.

Here I have overloaded the < operator for type Event which works when comparing two events. This is in my Event class:

```
bool Event::operator<(const Event &rhs) {
    if (yearnum < rhs.year()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (yearnum == rhs.year() && monthnum < rhs.month()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (monthnum == rhs.month() && daynum < rhs.day()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I declare my overloaded operator inside Event.h

```
bool operator<(const Event&);
```

I want to have sort() use my overloaded < operator when sorting an unsorted vector of Events. "events" is the vector of Event types. When doing this sort I keep getting: no match for ‘operator<’ error.
This is in my Schedule.cc file:

```
void Schedule::read(istream &in) {
    string s;

    while (in >> s) {
        try {
            Event e(s);

            if (events.size() == 0) {
                events.push_back(e);
            }
            else {
                events.push_back(e);

                sort(events.begin(), events.end(), [](const Event &lhs, const Event &rhs) {
                    return lhs < rhs; // this is where the error occurs.
                });

            }
        }
        catch(...) {
            in.setstate(ios::failbit);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a proper `operator<` overload, then you don't need to provide the third ordering argument to `std::sort`, it will use `<` by default. So plain `sort(events.begin(), events.end())` will work just fine (once you fix the current problem).

Answer (score 3):

```
[](const Event &lhs, const Event &rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs; // this is where the error occurs.
}
```

Both `lhs` and `rhs` are references to ***const*** objects, as you see here.

```
bool Event::operator<(const Event &rhs) {
```

Your `<` overload is ***not*** a `const` class method. Only `const` methods can be invoked on `const` objects.

As an aside it is not necessary to explicit pass this closure to `std::sort`, once fixed the `<` overload should be sufficient to do the job entirely by itself.

Comment: Yep I just found that. Thank you